# Correlation between height/top properties and anchors

Tags: html, css

Given the following snippet:

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#container {
  width: 600px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: cyan;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#inner1 {
  position: relative;
  width: 40%;
  height: calc(100% - 50px);
  background-color: #f00;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

#inner2 {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #ff0;
}

#footer {
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 600px;
}

#ancore {
  background-color: pink;
  margin-top: 30px;
  width: 40%;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="ancore">
      <a href="#gobottom">Bottom</a> <a href="#top">Top</a>
  </div>
  <div id="inner1">
    <a name="top"></a>
    <div id="inner2">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi.</p>  
    </div>
    <a name="gobottom"></a>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="footer">
  <p>My Footer</p>
</div>
```

I would like to understand a few things about it.

**1)**

Am i forced to use the *calc* function to set the *height* property to the #inner1 div?

In a real world situation could be very hard for me to understand all the different involved heights.
In this very simple case, that 50px comes from 30px for the margin-top and 20px for the footer (even if i did not set an height value to it!).

Is there any different way to get the same behaviour of the snippet?

**2)**

If i'm wrong to write the formula inside the calc function, the anchors work bad and the divs get moved from their original position. In particular this happens when the height is too high.

Why does this happen?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I don't understand #2. Unsure what you mean by "anchors work bad and the divs get moved from their original position".  Does your demo show that issue? If not, could you add a snippet or some code that demonstrates that problem?

Comment: just try "calc(100% - 5px)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**#1**
You are attempting to set the height of the element to the height of the parent element (`#container` in your OP), minus the height of the *sibling* element (`#ancore`) and all of it's offsets (margin, etc) in that same parent.

**If the parent is a set height**, such as your example, you can manually do the calculation and simply set the `height:250px;` in the css.

**If the parent is a variable height** (such as a %) then `calc()` become handy. With width, this behavior (take up all the space that's not already taken up by sibling elements) can be accomplished with floats. Heights are trickier - and `calc()` is the typical solution. If you need a workaround without `calc()`, such as for browsers that don't support it, your only HTML/CSS option is to use a table:

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#container {
  width: 600px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: cyan;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-top:30px;
}
#container table{
  width:40%;
  height:100%;
  border-collapse:collapse;
}

#inner1 {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #f00;
}

#inner2 {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #ff0;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

#footer {
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 600px;
}

#ancore {
  background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr><th id="ancore"><a href="#gobottom">Bottom</a> <a href="#top">Top</a></th></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td id="#inner1">
          <div id="inner2">
            <a name="top"></a>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi.</p>  
            <a name="gobottom"></a>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<div id="footer">
  <p>My Footer</p>
</div>
```

**#2**
You would have to demonstrate this behavior, I cannot recreate what you describe given your original example. Try the above fixes, see if it helps.